# 28000 210 {[unixODBC]Failed to send the authentication packet; Could not flush socket buffer." -->DB error

Tags: database, tcl, unixodbc

While connecting the DB, I am facing the below issue

> 28000 210 {[unixODBC]Failed to send the authentication packet; Could
>   not flush socket buffer.

Can you please help me to resolve this?

Comment: Please could you give us a few more bits of information? What version of what database are we talking about here?

Comment: its our internal mysql db,  where we use postgress drivers to connect and in the client side we have tclodbc driver over unixodbc

Comment: What Tcl package are you using to connect?

Comment: unixODBC 2.3.4 and tclodbc2.3.1

Comment: If you're on a GNU/Linux system, your `unixodbc` package (or whatever it's called on your system) should provide the `isql` program. Can you verify you're able to connect to your DBMS instance using that program (to try to detect whether the problem is on the Tcl side or in the MySQL ODBC driver)?

Comment: And the tcl version used is 8.4

Comment: testtmpodbc-1 ~/unixODBC-2.3.4]$ ls
no isql such program, its on FREEBSD

Comment: I'm not too well-versed in FreeBSD but [this](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/databases/unixODBC/pkg-plist?view=markup&pathrev=397634) suggests the FreeBSD's `unixodbc` port should provide `isql` as `/bin/isql` if I parse the `pkg-dist` file correctly.

Comment: there is no such port available